# Add a parameter to all links - the ? and & so as to no broken links

Tags: php, html, url, parameters, hyperlink

We need to add a parameter to some links of our site (affiliate). Let's say it **parameter=x**
Only one question:
Is that enough to add **?parameter=x** if no question mark (**?**) detected on the link and **&parameter=x** if detected so as to all links still working?

I mean that we do not want to make any functionable link to go broken after the add of the parameter. The links amount is huge, we cannot test each one.

Could be exists any case, to make the link broken, that should taken into account during the add of the parameter?
The links are seo friendly, but they still have their own parameters with same logic (?/ &).

Comment: `https://example.com/something#fragment` would break your assumption of being able to just append a parameter to an arbitrary link. You should parse the link, insert your parameter into the query part (creating it if empty) and re-build the URL.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol do you have any suggestions for PHP functions that can help on that way?

Comment: [`parse_url()`](https://php.net/parse-url) to start. See the comments on that documentation link for an "unparse-url" to rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of code which parses links from array and updates specific query params, and pushed new results to new array keeping order of links.

This will fail if there is a port, user, or password field since we don't parse them from a string. But if you have cases like that you can easily add them.

Demo: https://replit.com/@kallefrombosnia/urls#main.php

```
$new = [];

foreach($urls as $key => $url){

    // Get query and host of url
    $query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $scheme = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
    $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $fragment = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);


    // Parse string 
    parse_str($query, $parts);

    // Do your logic here with $parts and change specific parts
    // Example change first parameters to crodocile
    $parts['parameter'] = 'crodocile';

    $changed = $parts;

    $newquery = http_build_query($changed);

    $new[] = implode('', [$scheme, '://' , $host, $path, '?', $newquery, $fragment ? "#".$fragment : '']);

}

var_dump($new);
```